# BeginForm Helper with specific route and pass data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, razor, routes

I've seen a lot of example where i saw something like that :

```
    .BeginForm(action, controller, Model, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

And like that :

```
      .BeginRouteForm(routeName, new { controller = controller, action = action }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Does anyone know a way to mix it ? I need to pass Model to my controller specifiying a route which is not the default route.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this overload of `Html.BeginForm` helper.

```
@Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod"
, "ControllerName"
, new { yourAdditionalParam = "value1", yourAdditionalParam2 = "value2" } // here your additional route params
, FormMethod.Post
, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

If you have different route just pass your additional parameters where I put a comment. If your routes configured right way MVC routing get rigth route from it.

Comment: If i do this i have "?yourAdditionalParam=Namespace.ClassName" and i want to pass the entire model not his name

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying achive by passing whole model. Anyway if model properties match route params it will work. But are you sure that you want it to pass like this? All models properties should be inside form not in definition.

Comment: you're right, i don't need to pass the whole model, just tree properties. I just will send them. Thanks for your help